# NSDateFormatter dateFromString incorrect

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

I am setting the value of a `UITableViewCell`'s `detailTextLabel` to the current date and am then allowing the user to modify that date using a `UIDatePicker`. I set the text label like this

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a MM/dd/YYYY"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

This sets the text label properly, and it displays something like `08:20 AM 08/07/2015`. This is the desired output. When the user selects this cell, I want the `date` property of my date picker to be set to the date displayed in the cell. To implement this, I have the following in my `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a MM/dd/YYYY"];

NSString *dateString = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].detailTextLabel.text;
self.datePicker.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

However, rather than setting the date to the one that is in the cell, this sets the date of the picker to `08:20 AM 12/21/2014`, which is not what it should be. Logging `dateString` outputs the correct string that is in the table view cell.

Is there a reason that I am experiencing this issue?

Comment: Check the `datePicker.date  dateFormater`. I think it should be same as the `dateString` `dateFormater`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year portion of your formatter string should be `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of @"hh:mm a MM/dd/**YYYY**" formatter try to use @"hh:mm a MM/dd/**yyyy**".

According to the Apple's docs:

*"A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year."*

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1